# JQuery test if Div has been hidden and clear form fields if it has been hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a number of div's that can be expanded using:

```
$('.adddriver1').click(function(){
$("#additionaldriver1").slideToggle();
return false;
});
```

I just change the div id as I need to.
The fields in this div can then be filled out.

If the person clicks the button to hide the div I need to check if anything was entered and then clear the fields.
I am trying:

```
$("#additionaldriver1").change(function(){
if($("#additionaldriver1").is(":hidden")){
$("#Driver2FirstName").val('');
$("#Driver2LastName").val('');
}
});
```

The html is:

```
     <a href="#"><img src="images/adddriver.gif" alt="" width="203" height="20" border="0" class="adddriver1" /></a>
</div>

<div id="additionaldriver1">
    <h1>Section 2.2 - <span>Additonal Driver 1 Information</span></h1>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">

      <tr>

        <td width="34%" valign="middle"><strong>Additional Driver 1 </strong></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

But it does not clear the fields.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance, Warren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the callback:

```
$('.adddriver1').click(function(){
    $('#additionaldriver1').slideToggle('slow',function(){
        if($(this).is(':hidden'))
        {
            $('#Driver2FirstName').val('');
            $('#Driver2LastName').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it automatically opens the div without having to click on the button. I need to have that div hidden initially. It doesn't clear the fields when I close it and then reopen it.

Comment: :) You should still use your click handler. See the updated code.

Comment: What would be the best way to clear a radio button and dropdown list?

Comment: Select you'd clear the same as the text fields. Radios you'd iterate and set the checked property to false `$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){$(this).prop('checked',false);});`

Comment: Another related question.
What would the best way be to validate any of the fields if the div is visible and the form is submitted?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for all of your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Is $("#additionaldriver1") a div? If it is I don't think it will fire a change event. You'd be better calling your hide code in a callback from the slidetoggle function (code below not tested) -

```
$("#additionaldriver1").slideToggle('medium',function () {
  if($("#additionaldriver1").is(":hidden")){
    $("#Driver2FirstName").val('');
    $("#Driver2LastName").val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: Arrghh - beaten to the punch by AlienWebguy!

Comment: Wow you answered after me and got the accept - how'd you pull that off? :)

Comment: There was a subliminal hidden message in my answer suggesting it should be accepted - the power of subliminality is going to make me bigger than Skeet!